# Moving text in an <a>

Tags: html, css

I would like to push the text down to be centered in the green part, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I've been messing around with it for some time, but I'm still a novice. Any help would be appreciated. I've added the HTML and CSS below.

[image]

```css
    .beerimgcontainer {
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      margin-right: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .beerimgcontainer a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .beerimgcontainer span {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 23px;
      font-family: champagne;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .beerimgcontainer:hover {
      background: #165a11;
      color: white;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #3c8837;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .beerimgcontainer:hover span {
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="beerimgcontainer">
      <a href="mug.html">
        <img src="images/text2.png" class="positionimg" alt="Mug">
        <span>Mug</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`img` and `span` are inline elements. They are initially next to each other. Since your image covers the whole width (that's available; 300px on parent div), it pushes the `span` down. Margin on the span wouldn't work.

What you should do is to set `display: block` on the `span` and then set a margin:

```
.beerimgcontainer span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/d7Lgt28m/)